# RewriteCond writing help

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to write a RewriteCond which checks for "blogs" word in request_uri, only then proceed ahead.

Something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xml/abc/http://blogs.*
```

is this syntactically correct?

Any help would be appreciate on this.

Comment: also i need to have a version which escapes slashes and colon after http.

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_URI won't contain the hostname.  If you're trying to detect http://blogs.yoursite.com you need to use HTTP_HOST

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blogs\. [NC]
RewriteRule ...
```

edit:

I don't think you can decode the url, so just skip the encoded parts in your regex.  You don't even need a RewriteCond :

```
RewriteRule ^/?xml/abc/(http.+blogs\..*) /foo/bar?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answere Rob , I will be getting http url as appended url, something like this http://mysite.com/xml/abc/http://blogs.mysite.com , so i think REQUEST_URI shud detect the blogs url

Comment: But how do i get the encoded version of RewriteCond say for e.g if the request url is like this http://mysite.com/xml/abc/http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.mysite.com

Comment: thanks @Rob , was able to get it correct using RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xml/djml/http.*blogs.*